# How to pass a value from HTML to Java class

Tags: java, html

I have created a form in HTML, that contains several fields describing new item, that user would like to add to the list of all items:

```html
<form v-on:submit.prevent="addItem" class="mt-3">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="input-field">
      <div class="label-styling">Category</div>
      <select v-model="selected" class="form-control">
        <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
        <option v-for="category in categories" v-bind:value="categories">{{category}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field">
      <div class="label-styling">Title</div>
      <input type="text" v-model="title" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="input-field">
      <div class="label-styling">Description</div>
      <input type="text" v-model="description" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="input-field">
      <div class="label-styling">Reference</div>
      <input type="text" v-model="refNumber" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="input-field">
      <div class="label-styling">Image URL</div>
      <input type="text" v-model="imageURL" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="input-field">
      <div class="label-styling">Stock</div>
      <input type="text" v-model="stock" class="form-control col-lg-2">
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

And I would like to read and save the passed values from frontend on backend, in a Java class. Could You please recommend me a good article / video about that process, or just quickly guide me through it? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways one could create a Java backend. 
Just to give a few pointers: [Java Servlets](https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-servlet-quick-start-tomcat-xml-config), [Spring](https://spring.io/guides).

Once you set up your API endpoints you can pass the values using the form you created.